# Multiple setInterval() issue with AJAX calls - (cooldown applied to items in inventory)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I am having trouble making the following code working properly. The correct behavior should be > on _loadInventory() apply _loadCooldowns() on all .cooldown items (a countdown). This works fine but the problems start when one of the items finishes its cooldown and refreshes the inventory (_loadInventory()). There seems to be an interval stuck that keeps reloading the _loadInventory, breaking the app. I am always clearing all the intervals and even purging the intervals array. I hope the code below will make more sense

```
// Loading the inventory
function _loadInventory(){
    // Fetching the inventory from PHP
    _ajaxFetch("php/ajax/conq-get-inventory.php", {ord : 0}).done(function(data){
        // Clearing inventory
        $('.inventory-field').each(function(){
            $(this).html('');
        })

        // Adding the data to html
        $.each(data.html, function(key, value){
            $('.inventory-field[data-inventory-field-id="' + key + '"]').html(value);
        })

        // HERE i am cleaning all the old intervals             
        $.each(intervals, function(key, value){
            clearInterval[intervals[key]];
        })

        // HERE i am clearing the intervals array           
        intervals = [];
        //buffs = [];

        // Teoretically now there should be no intervals, so run the function that assigns the cooldowns for each item in the inventory         
        _loadCooldowns();

        // Other not important code
        $('#pesos-wrapper').html(data.pesos);
        _startTooltip()
        $('#trash-wrapper').droppable({ 
            accept: ".item", 
            drop: function(event, e){
                _ajaxFetch("php/ajax/conq-delete-item.php", {id: e.draggable.attr('data-item-id')}, 1).done(_loadInventory);
                e.draggable.remove();
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Here is the code that applies the cooldown to all the items that have .cooldown class

```
function _loadCooldowns(){
    // If there are any cooldown 
    if($('.cooldown').length > 0){
        // Apply the cooldown for each item
        $('.cooldown').each(function(){
            // The cooldown element
            var e = $(this);
            // Just a check
            if($(this).attr('data-cooldown-type') == 'item'){
                // The id of the item (unique)
                var id = $(this).attr('data-item-id');
                // Start the interval and save it to the Intevals array
                intervals[id] = setInterval(function(){ _applyCooldown(e, id) }, 1000);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the actual function inside the Interval

```
function _applyCooldown(e, id){
    // Get the current time in seconds
    var time = parseInt(e.attr('data-cooldown'));

    // If the time is more than 0
    if(time > 0){
        // Add new time             
        if(time > 60){
            time--;
            e.html(Math.round(time / 60) + 'm');
            e.attr('data-cooldown', time);
        }
        else{
            time--;
            e.html(time + 's');
            e.attr('data-cooldown', time);
        }
    }

    // Otherwise
    else{
        // Remove this cooldown element
        e.remove();
        // RELOAD INVENTORY! Here when the inventory is reloaded it should clear all the current intervals and start the full procedure again
        // But that does not happen, some intervals get stuck and persist
        // Resulting in anonymous intervals being run in the background that keep reloading the inventory all the time as their time is not > 0 (most likely undefined)
        _loadInventory();
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated as I am already pulling my hair out. Thanks!!

[image: A small image to see it in action for overview]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

A really simple fix I think could help a lot of people.

Instead of saving the interval to an array I did the following:

```
window.interval_id = window.setInterval(function(){ _applyCooldown(e, id) }, 1000);
```

Now every time I want to reset the intervals I just do

```
function _resetIntervals(){

    for (var i = 1; i <= window.interval_id; i++){

         window.clearInterval(i);
         window.i = false;

    }

}
```

Works like a charm